# EnumChildWindows fails for the child dialog of the parent window

Tags: c#, winapi, window, controls

In my program, i'am trying to find the element on the window, which is created by the other parent window. I want to find the specific button and click on it. For example i took the "settings" window of my browser. The following code:

```
IntPtr hwNd = FindWindow("MyBrowserClass", "Settings"); 

 List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
            GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
            try
            {
                Win32Callback childProc = new Win32Callback(EnumWindow);
                EnumChildWindows(hwNd, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
                uint errorCode = GetLastError();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                    listHandle.Free();
            }
            return result;
```

I'm getting the `GetLastError() = 1008` ERROR_NO_TOKEN. I looked in spy++, the window styles are:

```
WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
```

And extended styles are:

```
WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_RIGHT_SCROLLBAR | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE
```

How do i get the controls of the child window of some other window?

Comment: Don't call `GetLastError` unless a function actually fails - the result is meaningless.

Comment: And in any case you shouldn't call GetLastError directly from .NET, you should use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error.

Comment: And `Marshal.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` relies on `SetLastError = true` in your `DllImport` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ultimate `EnumChildWindows` import use a `SetLastError` attribute as suggested by David?

I think a good example is how Microsoft has implemented calls to `EnumChildWindows` in .NET: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Internal/AutomationProxies/Misc.cs

```
        internal unsafe static bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, NativeMethods.EnumChildrenCallbackVoid lpEnumFunc, void* lParam)
        {
            bool result = UnsafeNativeMethods.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, lpEnumFunc, lParam);
            int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
 
            if (!result)
            {
                ThrowWin32ExceptionsIfError(lastWin32Error);
            }
 
            return result;
        }
```

The callback type `EnumChildrenCallbackVoid` is in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Win32/NativeMethods.cs

```
        internal unsafe delegate bool EnumChildrenCallbackVoid(IntPtr hwnd, void* lParam);
```

And the `EnumChildWindows` in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Win32/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs

```
        [DllImport(ExternDll.User32, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal unsafe static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, NativeMethods.EnumChildrenCallbackVoid lpEnumFunc, void* lParam);
```

The DLL name is in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Win32/ExternDll.cs

```
        internal const string User32 = "user32.dll";
```

The `ThrowWin32ExceptionsIfError` example of handling the errors is in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Internal/AutomationProxies/Misc.cs

```
        internal static void ThrowWin32ExceptionsIfError(int errorCode)
        {
            switch (errorCode)
            {
                case 0:     //    0 ERROR_SUCCESS                   The operation completed successfully.
                    // The error code indicates that there is no error, so do not throw an exception.
                    break;
 
                case 6:     //    6 ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE            The handle is invalid.
                case 1400:  // 1400 ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE     Invalid window handle.
                case 1401:  // 1401 ERROR_INVALID_MENU_HANDLE       Invalid menu handle.
                case 1402:  // 1402 ERROR_INVALID_CURSOR_HANDLE     Invalid cursor handle.
                case 1403:  // 1403 ERROR_INVALID_ACCEL_HANDLE      Invalid accelerator table handle.
                case 1404:  // 1404 ERROR_INVALID_HOOK_HANDLE       Invalid hook handle.
                case 1405:  // 1405 ERROR_INVALID_DWP_HANDLE        Invalid handle to a multiple-window position structure.
                case 1406:  // 1406 ERROR_TLW_WITH_WSCHILD          Cannot create a top-level child window.
                case 1407:  // 1407 ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS     Cannot find window class.
                case 1408:  // 1408 ERROR_WINDOW_OF_OTHER_THREAD    Invalid window; it belongs to other thread.
                    throw new ElementNotAvailableException();
 
                // We're getting this in AMD64 when calling RealGetWindowClass; adding this code
                // to allow the DRTs to pass while we continue investigation.
                case 87:    //   87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
                    throw new ElementNotAvailableException();
 
                case 8:     //    8 ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY         Not enough storage is available to process this command.
                case 14:    //   14 ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY               Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
                    throw new OutOfMemoryException();
 
                case 998:   //  998 ERROR_NOACCESS                  Invalid access to memory location.
                case 5:     //    5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
 
                case 121:   //  121 ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT               The semaphore timeout period has expired.
                case 258:   //  258 WAIT_TIMEOUT                    The wait operation timed out.
                case 1053:  // 1053 ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
                case 1460:  // 1460 ERROR_TIMEOUT                   This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
                    throw new TimeoutException();
 
                default:
                    // Not sure how to map the reset of the error codes so throw generic Win32Exception.
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }
        }
```

Hopefully this gives some inspiration on the error handling.